# How can I make XML based API requests using Express Node.js?

Tags: node.js, xml, api

I would like to send an API request to https://api-test.onlineszamla.nav.gov.hu/invoiceService/queryTaxpayer and they expect an XML, as a sample provided below. What is the appropriate syntax in Node.js that processes this request? Unfortuantely I couldn't find this out from the API documentation.

EDIT: part of the XML contents will be from user data, part of it from input fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><QueryTaxpayerRequest xmlns="http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/api">
    <header>
        <requestId></requestId>
        <timestamp></timestamp>
        <requestVersion></requestVersion>
        <headerVersion></headerVersion>
    </header>
    <user>
        <login></login>
        <passwordHash></passwordHash>
        <taxNumber></taxNumber>
        <requestSignature></requestSignature>
    </user>
    <software>
        <softwareId></softwareId>
    </software>
    <taxNumber></taxNumber>
</QueryTaxpayerRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XML parser and then Set the response type as XML like below :

```
var xml = require('xml');

response.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

response.send(xml(YOUR_XML_OBJECT));
```

in the above I have used [XML](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml) as the parser, you should be able to use any other available packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [xmlbuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder) to make creating xml string easier.

```js
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

var obj = {
  root: {
    xmlbuilder: {
      repo: {
        '@type': 'git', // attributes start with @
        '#text': 'git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git' // text node
      }
    }
  }
};

var xml = builder.create(obj).end({ pretty: true});
console.log(xml);
```

And then you can use any library to make the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and use the xml string above in the body.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me awesome.

```
var Request = require("request");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.text())

app.post("/api/getXML", (req, res) => {
    Request.post({
        "headers": { "content-type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"},
        "url": "<url which return xml response>",
        "body": req.body
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.send(error)
        }
        console.log("XML body :",body);
        res.send(body);
    });
});
```

The idea got from the link https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/10/consume-remote-api-data-nodejs-application/